# ZTE F660, /bin/sh: Access Denied

Tags: unix, remote-access, telnet

I have a problem with my router ZTE F660, V5.2.10P1T22S (btw same problem with F609). If I do telnet from device which is connected directly to the router (LAN/WiFi) - I get full telnet access. But if I do remote telnet from remote device - I can't use most of commands, like `echo`, `reboot`, `sendcmd 1 DB set ...` and others. System returns me this:

```
/ # echo $PATH  
/bin/sh: Access Denied.
```

I'm a bit stuck with this problem, have no idea where to search to find the solution or maybe just a cause.
`Mount` shows this:

```
/ # mount
ubi:rootfs_ubifs on / type ubifs (ro,relatime)   
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)  
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)  
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600,ptmxmode=000)
/dev/mtdblock7 on /data type jffs2 (rw,relatime)
/dev/mtdblock4 on /tagparam type jffs2 (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /var type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=15360k)
/dev/mtdblock5 on /userconfig type jffs2 (rw,relatime) 
none on /mnt type ramfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime)
none on /proc/bus/usb type usbfs (rw,relatime)
```

`echo $PATH` shows this:

```
/ # echo $PATH  
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Both commands were executed on PC connected directly to the router.
The only user is allowed to connect router via CLI:

```
<DM name="TS_UName" val="root"/>
<DM name="TS_UPwd" val="Zte521"/>
```

Tried to binwalk this file `/bin/sh` but it shows me that this file is just a couple of Unix paths and I have no idea if it can be useful.
There are all things my router allows me to do and unfortunately there is no sudo:

```
/ # help   
Built-in commands:  
 --------------------   
. : break cd chdir continue eval exec exit export false hash help local  
 pwd read readonly return set shift times trap true type ulimit umask  
 unset wait [ ash awk brctl busybox cat chmod chrt cmp cp cut date df  
 diagput echo egrep free fuser getty grep hexdump hostname ifconfig init  
 insmod kill killall linuxrc ln login ls lsmod mkdir mknod mount mv passwd  
 ping ping6 ps pwd reboot rm rmdir rmmod sed sh sleep sync taskset test  
 tftp top traceroute umount wget
```

Has anyone encounter a similar problem? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: "if I do remote telnet from remote device " probably a security setting in the router to prevent intrusion.

Comment: Yeah, it's very possible. But I don't know how to find this setting, that's a problem. All I found is a firewall level setting in web-interface, but even disabling firewall doesn't help.

Comment: When you telnet from your WIFI/LAN you are connecting using your NAT private addresses, which seems to be enabled in your router. A remote device uses  your router's public address,  which is disabled for telnet by default (and should be kept this way). Telnet is an unsafe remote connection protocol. Do you have an SSH connection option by any chance?

Comment: Yeah, router's public address is disabled for telnet by default, but this is not hard to change, so my router allows me to telnet it using this public address. Problem is not in connecting to the router but in having no permit to do all the commands... Btw router has SSH connection option, I tried to configure it, but with no success for now.

Comment: facing same issue, still in progress: https://github.com/ndunks/modem-indihome-f609/tree/master/firmware-V8

Answer (score -2):

I found a txt file called "Authority.txt" in /etc/tdsec location. It was encrypted and I could view is through the routerpassview software. I think, that's the reason for that "Access Denied" error.

Extracted from Authority.txt

r_permit_list]

sendcmd

rtrace

tdmtool

cat

epondbg

ip

tc

iptables

multicast_test

igmptest

gponctl

gpondbg

gpontest

epontst

ethdriver_test

switchtst

opticaltst

ps

ls

cd

pwd

top

date

grep

ping

ifconfig

redir

athstats

apstats

tso

bobtest read

exit

killall hostapd

hostapd

ethswctl

dw

ftest

/etc/rdpa_init.sh

/etc/rdpa_gpon_init_m.sh

bs

slctool

dsptool

iwpriv

iwconfig

wlanconfig

iwlist

wl

qcsapi_sockrpc

wlctl

nvram

hexdump

usbtest

mtd_debug

setmac show

upgradetest gdefconf

fpga -r

[ops_permit_list]

echo ipdst [ipfmt] > /proc/net/remote_mirror_conf/conf

echo ipsrc [ipfmt] > /proc/net/remote_mirror_conf/conf

echo switch 1 > /proc/net/remote_mirror_conf/conf

echo switch 0 > /proc/net/remote_mirror_conf/conf

echo dir lan > /proc/net/remote_mirror_conf/conf

echo dir wan > /proc/net/remote_mirror_conf/conf

echo dir all > /proc/net/remote_mirror_conf/conf

sendcmd 1 DB p UserInfo

sendcmd 1 DB p DevAuthInfo

echo 0 > /proc/net/fastforward/hff_power

echo 0 > /proc/net/fastforward/ffe_power

echo 1 > /proc/net/fastforward/ffe_entry_clear

echo panic 3 >backup

echo watchdog 3 >backup

echo monitorwdg 3 >backup

echo 0 > /proc/zteinfo/watchdog/conf

echo 0 > /proc/zteinfo/factory/factorymode

echo 1 > /proc/zteinfo/factory/factorymode

echo 2 > /proc/zteinfo/factory/factorymode

killall vsftpd

vsftpd -s &

tmtst

echo 0 100 > /sys/devices/platform/ponmac/gmac/bwMap

echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/ponmac/gmac/fulDbg

echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/ponmac/gmac/fulDbg

sendcmd 132 omcidebug recalpath

brctl showmacs br0

brctl show

brctl showstp br0

brconfig getfdblimit br0

brconfig getageing br0

ebtables -L --Lc

reboot

upgradetest getver

upgradetest setsyn

serialctrl on

serialctrl off

[file_forbid_list]

ftp_password.log

options.o

ftpuserinfo_p.log

ftpuserinfo.log

samba

smbpasswd

hotspotd

inadyn.conf

ipsec.secrets

ipsec.conf

dipc.conf

dtdns.conf

lua_session

lua_tmp

wlan2.4g_scan_result

wlan5g_scan_result

scanresult

wlanscan

secath

hostapd.conf

wpa_supplicant.conf

mt7603e.dat

mt7612e.dat

userconfig.txt

nvram

.lua

[forbid_list]

sendcmd 1 DB p UserInfo

sendcmd 1 DB p DeviceInfo

sendcmd 1 DB p DevAuthInfo

sendcmd 1 DB p TelnetCfg

sendcmd 1 DB all

sendcmd 1 DB save

sendcmd 1 DB set

sendcmd 1 DB addr

sendcmd 1 DB delr

sendcmd 1 DB rreset

sendcmd 1 DB lreset

sendcmd 1 DB reset

sendcmd 1 DB saveasy

sendcmd 1 DB decry

sendcmd 2 BoardControl set 34008

sendcmd 2 BoardControl hlt

sendcmd 132 omcidebug recalpath

sendcmd 132 omcidebug remoterestoredefault

gponctl stop

gponctl start

gpontest -slonglaser

epontst -slonglaser

epontst -sconnect

epontst -stxpower

switchtst -w

switchtst -spen

switchtst -sportenable

switchtst -splinkpara

switchtst -slinkpara

switchtst -wphy

sendcmd 61 telnetd ShowCfg

Comment: I found file "authority.txt" in /etc, for some reason my router has no "tdsec" directory. But this file is encrypted as well. Could you please tell me how did you decrypt it? Binwalk shows nothing:(